# Call a component programmatically in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I want to use this function when hovering with the mouse over `<li>` to run a detail component.

```
  findId(id:number){
     console.log(id)
  }
```

when this function is running must send id to this component:

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() id:number;
    constructor() { }
   ngOnInit() {
   }
  }
```

and this is HTML file:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let cat of cats" >
    <a (mouseover)="findId(cat.id)">{{cat.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[demo of my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-programicly-component-in-angular6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**How can I do this?**

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: Do you want to pass id from your 'findId()' function to other component ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Will there be only one `DetailComponent`? Where will the component be put in the template?

Comment: @HarunYılmaz you see my ample code : if you see that you undrestand my question . i need when mouse hover to `li` run the component and show it in appcomponent.html

Comment: @Mr-Programer Your code does not help understand your question. See [ask], the sections titled "Introduce the problem before you post any code" and "Help others reproduce the problem".

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok. my question is this . how can i show `appdetailcomponent` when mouse is hover in `li`

Comment: Do you want add component dynamically to your dom? if so then you may have to look at ComponentFactoryResolver https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/angular-2-dynamically-render-components/

Comment: Please [edit] your clarifications to the question.

Comment: I've already seen your example. I couldn't see `<app-detail></app-detail>` anywhere in the template.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz i need  `appdetailcomponent` when mouse is hover in `li` without use this way `<app-detail></app-detail>`

Comment: Then your answer is here: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References to my answer is taken from the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). Going through this link would help.

There can be different scenarios. Lets have a look at them.

- DetailComponent is the child of your current component
- DetailComponent is the sibling of your current component
- DetailComponent is the parent of your current component

**Scenario 1**: DetailComponent is the child of your current component

As described by @nguyen in his answer
Since you have defined `@input` decorator in your DetailComponent, if the DetailComponent is the child of your current component and the selector of your `DetailComponent` is suppose `app-detail` then in your html template you will call the detail component and pass the value

```html
<app-detail[id]="selectedId"></app-detail>
```

provided `selectedId` is the class variable of your current component which holds the id that you want to pass to the DetailComponent

i.e suppose your function

```
findId(id:number){
     console.log(id)
  }
```

is working and you can see the id in console, then modify your function

```
findId(id:number){
     console.log(id);
     this.selectedId = id;
  }
```

---

For **Scenario 2** and **Scenario 3** have a look at the documentation where you have the choice of either passing the values using event emitters.

Otherwise what I like to do is I create a service and that service holds the values that are common to multiple components. Then I import the service in the components that uses these values.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataStoreService {
  selectedId: string;
}
```

In your Current Component:

```
export class CurrentComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dataStoreService: DataStoreService) { }
    ngOnInit() {}

    findId(id:number){
     this.dataStoreService.selectedId = id;
  }
  }
```

Then in you DetailComponent import the service

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dataStoreService: DataStoreService) { }
    ngOnInit() {}
  }
```

And in your DetailComponent html template

```html
<div>{{dataStoreService.selectedId}}</div>
```

if CurrentComponent and DetailComponent are siblings then they both will import this service and use the same variable as a model which will be updated or displayed by the components.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the DetailComponent is defined with the selector `app-detail`

You need to assign the `id` from the input to it

```
<app-detail [id]="assignedId"></app-detail>
```

and in the component, where you contain the detail component, you need to assign the value to assignedId (or whatever you name it)

```
public assignedId;

public findId(id:number) {
    this.assignedId = id;
}
```

hope this help

Comment: i need pass  programmatically

Comment: the line ```this.assignedId = id;``` pass it programmatically. In any case, you need to define the input of the component. If you don't define the template of the component anywhere, it won't be appeared